# OutOfMemoryException on spring job execution context

Tags: out-of-memory, spring-batch

I'm getting the below error when I put a large object in the JobApplicationContext. The object is converted to JSON and saved in BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT, but not sure why we are getting the out of memory while processing the writer step.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:270)
   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:101)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1238)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1234)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1234)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1234)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:848)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1236)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter.writeJSONObject(MappedXMLStreamWriter.java:258)
   at org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter.writeEndDocument(MappedXMLStreamWriter.java:244)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxWriter.endNode(StaxWriter.java:149)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.WriterWrapper.endNode(WriterWrapper.java:37)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.path.PathTrackingWriter.endNode(PathTrackingWriter.java:48)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:83)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You are getting the OOM error because your object is too large. Try to minimize the size of data that is added to the job execution context (add only the bare minimum) or, if this is not possible, you need to increase the size of your JVM's memory.

Comment: Found the root cause of the issue. Spring batch saves the job application context data in the DB. To save the data, spring batch uses a serializer which creates a JSON string for the context.  Since that string is huge and it's in the memory, we got the out of memory exception.